# Ground and neutral switched in old wiring

Tags: electrical, electrical-panel, generator

The house I live in has old wiring I haven't ever really looked at much. I have decided to add solar so have started looking at it. We are off grid and currently the entire house comes out on a spliced together extension cord- spliced onto a formerly larger cable going to what was a gen shed far away. Looking at it closely I  notice the green ground wire is spliced onto the white neutral wire and the neutral wire is connected to a bare copper ground wire. The house is not actually grounded as far as I can tell- the ground wire just runs back to the generator. Is there a good reason they have done this? It seems odd to me. There is a circuit breaker panel that the main cable comes out of - the circuits going into it are wired normally in terms of colour convention, it's just this generator cord which has the colours reversed. Any advice?

Comment: There's lots wrong with this -- is replacing the spliced-together extension cord an option, and what gauge is the wire the cord's connected to anyway?

Comment: Pictures of the wiring at the generator, this mismatched splice and the connection to the panel would all be very helpful.

Answer (score 2):

I would say the splice was done in the dark by a person that was colour blind.

That or the neutral is broken somewhere in the extension and this is an old timers hack to fix.

Do the splice right and fix the broken wire or a better idea is to replace the whole cable.